# How to move right or left by 'x' characters in Bash?

Tags: bash

In bash sometimes I have very long commands where I need to edit some words. Right now I use **End/Home** to move end/start of the command, but what if I have to move say *x* characters in a line?

I need something like **xb/xw of VI**, but instead of words I need to move characters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about ditching emacs mode and switching to vi mode editing?

```
 set -o vi
```

and you have all the power of vi-like command line editing, like `3l` to go left three characters and `5B` to go back 5 words. The Pos 1 key then becomes `0` and End becomes `$`.

Answer (score 4):

In `emacs` mode, you can use <kbd>Meta</kbd><kbd>3</kbd><kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>b</kbd> to move back 3 characters, and <kbd>Meta</kbd><kbd>3</kbd><kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> to move forward 3 characters. For multi digit counts, you need to precede each digit with the <kbd>Meta</kbd> key (e.g., to move 10 characters back, <kbd>Meta</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>Meta</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>b</kbd>).

<kbd>Meta</kbd> is usually the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key, but may be the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key instead (on Mac OS X, for instance).

(Yes, `vi-command` mode makes it easier.)

There is a command, `universal-argument`, that allows you to type all the digits at once, but it is unbound by default. Bind it with, say,

```
bind "\C-a":universal-argument
```

then typing <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd> will enter you into an "argument" mode, prefixing the current line `(arg: 4)`, and allowing you to type digits to change the argument used by the next non-digit character you type. (See `universal-argument` in the `bash` man page for the full details.)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the command as below

Command:

```
cp some_file1 some_file2 some_file3 /root/Desktop
```

After executing the command do the following

```
^some_file2^some_file4
```

and it will execute the command

```
cp some_file1 some_file4 some_file3 /root/Desktop ;
```

What happened is the some_file2 is replaced by some_file4 and the command is executed

Comment: Hi!
Thanks for the help but this would not be practical as it means I have to execute the first command. It is kind of hack. Anyways I did learn something new from this method.